# Why does broadcastEval() not return the roles of a guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

**This is my code:**

```
await shardingManager.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.get('352896116812939264')`);
```

**This is what the above eval returns:**

```
{ members: {},
  channels: {},
  roles: {},
  presences: {},
  deleted: false,
  available: true,
  id: '352896116812939264',
  name: 'LenoxBot™',
  ...}
```

My question is now, why doesn't it **return the roles, channels, members,...**?

---

I tried even the following but it **didn't work** too:

```
await shardingManager.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.get('352896116812939264').roles`);
```

*(The bot has enough permissions to see all roles etc.)*

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "partial guild"? @PLASMAchicken

Comment: It could be because  `guild.members.client` is a circular reference and so node.js handles that by simply returning `{}`

Comment: Yes this could be and how to fix this then? @PLASMAchicken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue here is that in the stable versions things like [`Guild#roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles) are not yet JSON serializable, for example due to cirucal references ( [`guild.roles.first().client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=client) ) so node.js just returns `{}`.

Related: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3144

> [On the development branch, all Discord.js objects are JSON
>   serializable. Unfortunately, that change won't land until v12. ~ appellation](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3144#issuecomment-472491283)

As mentioned there you can either go with discord.js v12 or you need to serialize the Objects yourself.